# How to redirect to a particular component on a certain path

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a particular path, let call it bigComponent. Within the bigComponent there are a few smaller components that are switched to depending on the state of the bigComponent, we'll call them smallComponents. Inside one of the smallComponents there is a link to third formComponent which has onClose property, which trigers history.goBack. My goal is to redirect a user to the smallComponent. history.goBack is not currently a solution as the smallComponent doesn't have its own path. Right now, a user gets redirected to the bigComponent. Could you please direct me toward how I could redirect the user to the smallComponent instead? Probably, I need the bigComponent to be loaded with a certain state as a result of such redirect.

Comment: By `history.goBack` are you implying that you are using the `react-router` library?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what it is you are trying to do. It's difficult to help debug code if it can't be seen.

Answer (score 1):

"Probably, I need the bigComponent to be loaded with a certain state as a result of such redirect."

Yes, that may works. Probably not the best practice I think, but quite practical.

To pass state while redirecting, you can use either `history.push(path, [state])` or `history.replace(path, [state])` where state is an object and can be accessed via `location.state` from `useLocation`. Then you can initialize the bigComponent's state using the value.